# Wait for a specific time on a website to start a process

Tags: javascript, eval, imacros

I want to launch a process at very specific time.

The website has a time indicator:

> TAG POS=1 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:2:31:35PM

What I need to do is the following:

1. If the time is 2:45:00PM , WAIT= 0.2 SECONDS and then continue with the macro
2. If not, wait until 2:45:00PM is reached

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

> Mac OS X. El Capitan 10.11.2 firefox 44.0 TAG POS=1 TYPE=FONT
>   ATTR=TXT:2:31:35PM

Comment: Just so I understand - if the time is before 2:45:00PM, you want the page to remain open and wait until the right time, then wait a further 0.2 seconds, and then trigger a function?  It's not just a case of if the time is (or is after) 2:45:00PM when the page loads, then wait 0.2 seconds and trigger the function?

Comment: Hi Markus. Thank you for your feedback. I have been able to TAG the time so that it is 2:31:25PM it starts the process. However, if the macro fails in some other part (further down the command line) i want to be able to hit Play again on the macro. However, by definition, it will be later than 2:31:25PM so the way I set it up currently will not start until the next day! Any advise would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use JavaScript with imacros and make a time listener for the element indicate to time and if time is 2:45 PM the imacros code will be done.

assume that time indicator has ID="time"   and it contains text like " 2:44:54 PM "

```
do {
var time = window.content.document.getElementById("time"); //catch element
time = time.textContent; //get text inside will be " 2:44:54 PM "
time = time.trim();  //remove spaces around text not inside text now text will be "2:44:54 PM"
time = time.replace('PM','');  // case sensitive if it will be pm then add pm now text will be "2:44:54 "
time = time.trim(); // making sure no spaces around my text which will be only "2:44:54" or any thing
if (time =='2:45:00'){
//do your macro code
break;}   // break to exit while loop and continue code >>after while condition
}while(1);
//>>after while condition
```

Note that the file should be .js not .iim to execute JavaScript inside.
Here it is a simple tool to convert imacros code to JavaScript code [Imacros to JavaScript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imacros-codegen/) 
you can read more about JavaScript with imacros here [JavaScript-iMacros WIKI](http://wiki.imacros.net/JavaScript)

Comment: window.content.document will work on Firefox and JavaScript solution is working with firefox and internet explorer google chrome is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this will be helpful to you:

```
' e.g. one day waiting '
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 86400
TAG POS=1 TYPE=FONT ATTR=TXT:2:45:00PM

SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
WAIT SECONDS=0.2
' your further code '
```

---

If the time is more or equal to 2:45:00PM, you may try something like this:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 53100
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"2:4[5-9]:\d\dPM|2:5[0-9]:\d\dPM|([3-9]|1[0-2]):\d\d:\d\dPM"
```

Comment: Shugar, thank you very much! I have this part nailed down. What I am missing is (if the code fails later down the road) I want to be able to REPLAY the macro. So for example it would be something like "if the time is more or equal to 2:45:00PM" Thanks for any further feedback you might have!!!